# How to apply validation in angular 7 reactive forms on submit?

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

TS Code:

```
onSubmit(){
 if(this.Registration.invalid){
   return;
  }
alert('Thanks for submitting! Data:' + JSON.stringify(this.Registration.value));

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form class="admin-form" [formGroup]="Registration" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" id="Registration">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>username</mat-label>
        <input matInput class="matInput" placeholder="username" type="text" formControlName="username">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>person</mat-icon>
      <mat-error *ngIf="Registration.controls['username'].invalid && (Registration.controls['username'].dirty ||Registration.controls['username'].touched)">
        <div *ngIf="Registration.controls['username'].errors.required">
          username is required.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="Registration.controls['username'].errors.pattern">
          username must be characters and special characters.
        </div>
       </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-icon-button type="submit" value="submit">
    <i class="material-icons">send</i>
  </button>
</form>
```

Angular 7 reactive forms validation on the submit button, I want if there any
errors or input field empty, then the form should be not submitted successfully.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `!` because it returns *`true`* when the form in Invalid i.e it has errors and returns *`false`* when then the form is Valid like:

```
if (this.Registration.invalid) {
   return;
}

alert('Thanks for submitting! Data:' + JSON.stringify(this.Registration.value));
```

But it's better to use `form.valid` to check the form Validation, explain [`here`](https://itnext.io/valid-and-invalid-in-angular-forms-61cfa3f2a0cd)

So the change with `valid` is use `!`:

```
if (!this.Registration.valid) {
   return;
}

alert('Thanks for submitting! Data:' + JSON.stringify(this.Registration.value));
```

> Another way and Recommended:

You can also disable the button itself if the form is invalid so until the form gets valid the submit button will be `disabled` for ex:

```
[disabled]="!Registration.valid" OR [disabled]="Registration.invalid"
```

with button:

```
<button mat-icon-button type="submit" [disabled]="!Registration.valid" value="submit">
  <i class="material-icons">send</i>
</button>
```

[`Stackblitz_Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysjbps-ajr956)